# A greasy Rebus!

Tags: rebus

A short Rebus I just came up with.

[image: rebus]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> Top soil? S on top + OIL

Comment: Correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

Is this

> SOIL (S+OIL)?

blank text

Comment: You're not quite there yet.

Comment: @casey Am I on the right track?

Comment: You were closer with your first attempt.